# What is WKErrorDomain error 4 from WKWebView

Tags: javascript, xcode, swift, ios8, wkwebview

```
fatal error: LPWebView encounters an error: Error Domain=WKErrorDomain Code=4 
"A JavaScript exception occurred" UserInfo=0x79d9c700 
{NSLocalizedDescription=A JavaScript exception occurred}
```

I encountered this error when I tried to evaluate a JavaScript function with WKWebView.

I used `loadHTMLString` to load a template to the webview.

```
let bundle = NSBundle.mainBundle()

if let editorURL = bundle.URLForResource(self.kTemplateName, 
                                              withExtension: "html") {
  var error : NSError?
  //get html string from editor.html
  if let htmlString = String(contentsOfURL: editorURL, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: &error){
    if error != nil {
      assertionFailure("error encountered reading html string for \(error)")
    } else {
      self.loadHTMLString(htmlString, baseURL: bundle.bundleURL)
    }
  }

} else {
  assertionFailure("LPWebView template not found")
}
```

I wonder what this error code means and how to solve it?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

So if we dig into the headers:

```
/*! @constant WKErrorDomain Indicates a WebKit error. */
@availability(iOS, introduced=8.0)
let WKErrorDomain: String

/*! @enum WKErrorCode
 @abstract Constants used by NSError to indicate errors in the WebKit domain.
 @constant WKErrorUnkcnown                       Indicates that an unknown error occurred.
 @constant WKErrorWebContentProcessTerminated   Indicates that the Web Content process was terminated.
 @constant WKErrorWebViewInvalidated            Indicates that the WKWebView was invalidated.
 @constant WKErrorJavaScriptExceptionOccurred   Indicates that a JavaScript exception occurred.
 */
@availability(iOS, introduced=8.0)
enum WKErrorCode : Int {
    
    case Unknown
    case WebContentProcessTerminated
    case WebViewInvalidated
    case JavaScriptExceptionOccurred
}
```

Error code 4 corresponds to `JavaScriptExceptionOccurred`, or `WKErrorJavaScriptExceptionOccurred`.

In other words, the JavaScript function causes some error.

Probably not more here that you couldn't guess already. For resolution, I would suggest using the developer features of a web browser such as Safari, loading the HTML and debugging.

In fact, as explained in the [WWDC 2014 video, "Introducing the Modern WebKit API"](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/?id=206), your desktop Safari browser can *"inspect the `WKWebView` using the Safari web inspector, including any user scripts that you've injected."*

To use this, while the `WKWebView` is loaded in memory in your running app on the iOS simulator, open the desktop Safari browser and access **Develop** on the top menu bar then **iOS Simulator**. That will show a drop down of the web view's document objects.

For more info on debugging JavaScript, take a look at [Web Inspector: Understanding Stack Traces](https://www.webkit.org/blog/1544/web-inspector-understanding-stack-traces/)

Comment: Just a quick note that you can also connect the *Safari Web Inspector* to an actual device and not just the *iOS Simulator*. To do so, enable the Web Inspector in the Safari/Advanced settings on your device and then run your app as usual from Xcode. Your app will appear in the Connected Devices submenu of the Develop menu.

Comment: no problem! Thanks also for chipping in @St3fan that's good to know.

Comment: For me, the error was occurred by a single quote while executing `webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.title='\(shareTitle)';") ` script. The error disappeared when I wrote `webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.title=\"\(shareTitle)\";") ` script.