# Javascript exception when calling evaluateJavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, swift, wkwebview

**My goal:**

- Run jquery script to click "add to cart" button from a 'specific' third party website product page.

**Expected Result:**

Running the script via **evaluateJavaScript** from WKWebView should allow me to click on the checkout button and add the product to cart.

**Actual Result:**

Running my script via **evaluateJavascript** gives me a javascript exception(provided below):

```
Error Domain=WKErrorDomain Code=4 "A JavaScript exception occurred" UserInfo={
    WKJavaScriptExceptionLineNumber=0, 
    WKJavaScriptExceptionMessage=, 
    WKJavaScriptExceptionColumnNumber=0, 
    NSLocalizedDescription=A JavaScript exception occurred
}
```

Unlike similar questions related to getting a javascript exception from evaluateJavaScript, my exception was returning a much rather broad exception. "WKJavaScriptExceptionMessage" is usually very descriptive but there was nothing of value that I can take from it to fix my javascript issue.

When testing, script runs fine on the console of google chrome and safari inspector(for mobile). It was able to perform the expected results with no issue. So I'm not sure why I'm getting an exception in the first place when running the script from **evaluateJavascript**.

**If you are curious, this is my code from initializing/viewDidLoad:**

```
let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()
let contentController = WKUserContentController()

config.processPool = CurrentProcessPool.shared.getCurrentProcessPool()
config.websiteDataStore = WKWebsiteDataStore.default()
config.userContentController = contentController

let webViewModel = WKWebView(frame: window.bounds, configuration: config)
let productPageLink = "https://click.linksynergy.com/link?id=7yE5K5lr0eU&offerid=639733.3977&type=15&murl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.rebeccaminkoff.com%2F%2F%2Fproducts%2Fsandra-puffer-f19100911-khaki"
let url = myURL(string: productPageLink) 

DispatchQueue.main.async {
    webViewModel.load(URLRequest(url: url))
}
```

**This is where I load the script:**

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 5.0) {
        let size = "XXS"
        let myScript = """ 

        document.querySelector('.size-select [data-size-option = "\(size)" i]').click()
        document.querySelector('.add-to-cart').click()


        """

        webView.evaluateJavaScript(myScript, completionHandler: { (result, error) in
            print(result)
        print(error)
    })
}
```

Let me know if there are areas that need clarification and I would happily fill in that information.

**myScript printed content:**

```
     window.onerror = function(){
        return true;
        }

        document.querySelector('.size-select [data-size-option = "XXS" i]').click()
        document.querySelector('.add-to-cart').click()
```

**Any insights to why the javascript exception is not providing more detailed information would be great!**  Thanks!

Comment: I don't have a experience with wkwebview but, if your querySelector doesn't find an element then the `.click` will throw `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of null`. Maybe check that something is found before calling `.click`?

Comment: Can you print myScript contents and output here?

Comment: @Marco , thanks for the suggestion. I have updated my question with the printed out myScript content from above.

Comment: @ktilcu It usually will throw something along the lines of what you just mentioned but for this particular case it did not.

Comment: I think your selector is wrong, what's with that i at the end? If you are searching for a <i> tag i think that's not how it's supposed to be. Try erasing that i at the end maybe?

Comment: Thanks @Marco , I appreciate the suggestion. I removed the 'i' and I still get the same error. It's very disappointing that the exception description is not providing much meaning for me to pin point what could be the cause issue. Here is the error "Error Domain=WKErrorDomain Code=4 "A JavaScript exception occurred" UserInfo={WKJavaScriptExceptionLineNumber=0, WKJavaScriptExceptionMessage=, WKJavaScriptExceptionColumnNumber=0, NSLocalizedDescription=A JavaScript exception occurred})" . Traditional errors would give something along the ines of "Cannot read property.." and etc..

Comment: Could you please take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27953374/what-is-wkerrordomain-error-4-from-wkwebview